# Injective $\alpha:A \to B$ has surjective $\beta: B \to A$ such that $\alpha\beta = {\rm id}_A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\alpha  : A \to B$ be an injective function. Show that there is a surjective function
$\beta: B\to A$ such that $\alpha; \beta = {\rm id}_A$.

Comment: Why should I do that?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Comment: Did you bother to search the site, before writing the question into the Ask Question page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $y$ that belongs to the image of $\alpha$ there is exactly
one $x\in A$ with $\alpha\left(x\right)=y$. For such $y$ define
$\beta\left(y\right)=x$. Pick some $x_{0}\in A$ and define $\beta\left(y\right)=x_{0}$
for every $y$ that is not in the image of $\alpha$. It is evident
that $\beta\circ\alpha=1_{A}$ (not $\alpha\circ\beta$ as you mention
in your question).

Caution: If $A=\emptyset$ then there is a unique function $\alpha:\emptyset\rightarrow B$
that is vacuously injective. However, if $B\neq\emptyset$ then there
are no functions from $B$ to $\emptyset$. So this only works under
the extra (and mild) condition that $A\neq\emptyset\vee B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha: A \to Im(\alpha)$ is one to one. So you can just define $\beta:B \to A; x \mapsto \alpha^{-1}(x)$ for $x \in Im(\alpha)$, $x \mapsto x_0$ else for some $x_0 \in A$. This makes $\beta$ a surjective function and $\beta\alpha = id_A$.

Comment: Since when $0$ is an element of $A$?

Comment: just pick some $a\in A$ and give it the name $0$. Can only be done if $A$ is not empty.

Comment: Not $\alpha\beta=1_{A}$ but $\beta\alpha=1_{A}$.

Comment: @drhab: Using $0$ to denote an arbitrary element is of course fine if your language doesn't include the symbol $0$. But it's extremely bad practice to do so.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Agree with that. In fact I thought that the OP had commented that $0$ was not an element of $A$ (instead of you), and was trying to show him a way how he could still somehow use the incomplete answer.